# How do you return items using a SQL command that are the most recent based on a date time string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks like this:

```
location | object | date-time-string | id
--------------------------------------------
Login    | label  | 5/17/14 4:29:20  | 1
Login    | main   | 5/17/14 4:29:20  | 2
Login    | button | 5/17/14 4:29:20  | 3
Login    | name   | 5/17/14 4:29:20  | 4
Login    | passwd | 5/17/14 4:29:20  | 5
Login    | pic    | 5/17/14 4:29:20  | 6
Login    | label  | 5/16/14 1:13:10  | 7
Login    | main   | 5/16/14 1:13:10  | 8
Login    | button2| 5/16/14 1:13:10  | 9
```

I have this query:

```
select object from table where location = 'Login' order by time desc
```

I want to get a list of all the items in the 'object' column that are from the most recent time. The date-time-string is generated from `DateTime.Now` in C# and inserted into the sql table.

How do you return items using a SQL command that are the most recent based on a date time string?

Comment: The query you have will work correctly _if_ the column `time` (or `date-time-string`, which is it?) is actually a proper date data type. If it is a `VARCHAR()` column, you need to convert it into a datetime.

Comment: it's not a sql time stamp is a string that is inserted from a C# application.

Comment: Why is it a string when it was inserted from `DateTime.Now`? Don't store `datetime` as `varchar`.

Comment: @Tim - should I change data type to 'timestamp'?

Comment: @ma3str0: [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

Comment: I ran the command 'ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD CreatedDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (GetUtcDate())' and it added a created date column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a datetime field for dates. Really. No excuses.
2. Use [ISO-8601](http://xkcd.com/1179/) to represent date-time as string. No excuses.

If you are wrong on either of the above (as you are, inexcusable), then cast the string to a date time and sort by the casted value. In your case is `mm/dd/yy` which is [style 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
select object 
from table 
where location = 'Login' 
order by CONVERT(datetime, [date-time-string], 1), desc;
```

The performance will be abysmal, but you well deserve that for breaking all that is good and sound about handling dates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure , but try this:

```
SELECT object
FROM table a
INNER JOIN

(SELECT TOP 1 date-time-string
FROM table
ORDER BY date-time-string DESC) b

ON a.date-time-string=b.date-time-string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select location, object, date-time-string, id
from (
    select location, object, date-time-string, id
         , row_number() over (partition by object
                              order by date-time-string desc) as rn
    from T
) a
where rn = 1
```

If your date-time-string is not a datetime type, you might have to cast to to such for the order to work.

I see now that I probably misunderstood the question, I thought it where the last "object" of every kind. If it's all objects from the last time, do something like:

```
select location, object, date-time-string, id
from (
    select location, object, date-time-string, id
         , rank() over (order by date-time-string desc) as rn
    from T
) a
where rn = 1
```